# How delete detached database on disk by T SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, delete-file, detach

How delete detached database from disk using T-SQL?
I want to delete a detached database from my hard disk. What should I do in T-SQL? I want to create a database with the same name and I get this error in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio:

```
Cannot create file 'H:...\Restaurant_Data.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways:

1. Attach the database and drop it
2. Log-in interactively on the server and delete the files from the disk
3. Use xp_cmdshell (after enabling it), but don't forget to disable it (if it's not needed)